# BATCH Unable to join variables

Tags: batch-file

I don't know what I got wrong here. Please help!

```
if "House%Player1Block%==1" goto HouseEventP11
if "House%Player1Block%==2" goto HouseEventP12
echo.You landed on empty block. Claiming house.
echo.You now own block %Player1Block%.
set "House%Player1Block%=1"
```

Error was Goto was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if "House%Player1Block%==1" goto HouseEventP11
```

if syntax is: `if <value1> <comparator> <value2> command`
 So `"House%Player1Block%==1"` is value1, `goto` is the comparator - wait - what? `goto` isn't a comparator - `goto was unexpected at this time`.

Correct syntax:

```
if "House%Player1Block%" == "1" goto :HouseEventP11
```

(Note: the colon with `goto :label` is optional, but I like to have it to be consistent with the `call` command, where the colon is mandatory to call a label (without the colon, `call` would try to find another batchfile instead of a label))

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to have worked for me. Really happy with the help!